# KML Layer Watermark Removal

Tags: google-maps, kml, api, maps, kmz

Hello right now I have a google maps page with KML Layers from multiple online resources. However all of these layers especially those from noaa have giant watermarks that take up large portions of my small map. Is there anyway to remove these watermarks? Is there a paid KML/KMZ weather service I could use that doesn't have watermarks? The feeds I am using now are

```
     layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/kml/fop/fopbody.kml',
            {preserveViewport: true});

    layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/forecast/archive/latest_wsp34knt120hr_tenthDeg.kmz',
            {preserveViewport: true});

    layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month_depth_link.kml',
            {preserveViewport: true});

    layers[3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://activefiremaps.fs.fed.us/data/kml/conus_latest_lg_incidents.kml',
            {preserveViewport: true});

    layers[4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://w1.weather.gov/tcig/Tornado.kml?random=115233',
            {preserveViewport: true});
```

Comment: Watermarks are embedded in the network kml so no way to remove them as the data is retrieved from the noaa servers every 15 mins.

Comment: Is there a company that provides the same services as Noaa that doesnt have watermarks? I would pay the premium for such a service.

Comment: looks like you need to pay for that service

Comment: Whats the name of the company?